# Regarding execution of conditional operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

how the conditional operator executes in this printf statement

```
printf("%d==1 is ""%s",k,k==1?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

Answer (score 1):

It will executed as normal as it should be.

```
if(k == 1)
    printf("%d==1 is %s",k,"TRUE");
else  
    printf("%d==1 is %s",k,"FALSE");
```